# What is the homotopy type of the smash power of Moore spectra $(S/2)^{\otimes n}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $S/2$ be the mod $2$ Moore spectrum, and let $n \in \mathbb N$.

**Question:**
What is the homotopy type of the $n$th smash power $(S/2)^{\otimes n}$?

**Notes:**

- When $p$ is odd, we have $S/p \otimes S/p = S/p \oplus \Sigma S/p$, and so when $p$ is odd, we have $(S/p)^{\otimes n} = (S/p) \otimes \otimes^{n-1} (S\oplus \Sigma S) = \oplus_{i = 0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i} \Sigma^i S/p$.
- But for $p = 2$, the above formula fails for $n = 2$. In other words, $2 \neq 0$ as an endomorphism of $S/2$ (though $4 = 0$). We can see that $S/2 \neq (S/2) \oplus (\Sigma S/2)$ because $H^\ast(S/2;\mathbb F_2)$ has a $Sq^1$, so by the Cartan formula $H^\ast(S/2 \otimes S/2; \mathbb F_2)$ has a $Sq^2$, but $(S/2) \oplus (\Sigma S/2)$ doesn't have a $Sq^2$.
- I seem to remember that there is a formula for $n = 3$ involving $S/\eta$. If this is the case, then just by looking at mod $2$ homology it would have to be something like $(S/2)^{\otimes 3} = (S/2) \otimes ((S/\eta) \oplus \Sigma S \oplus \Sigma S)$, but I'm not sure how to convince myself that this is actually the case.

This question is related to [another old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381754/solving-polynomial-equations-in-spectra). And a [couple](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360804/is-the-mod-2-moore-spectrum-a-retract-of-a-shift-of-its-tensor-square?rq=1) of [similar questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85313/homotopy-type-of-tensors-of-moore-spectra?) has been asked before, but the answers only go so far as showing that $S/2 \otimes S/2$ does not split as $S/2 \oplus \Sigma S/2$ -- no positive results about understanding $(S/2)^{\otimes n}$ are mentioned.

Comment: Here are some minor comments. 1- starting at n=3 you will start to have summands split off of various different types. 2- there's no finitary expression. Even if you decompose these smash powers into irreducible summands, there are infinitely many inequivalent summands that appear. 3- you can ask the same question for the decomposition of the homology as a module over the Steenrod algebra. It's more approachable but still exhibits the same phenomena as 1&2.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, as shown in my answer to your `old question', arbitrary smash products of copies of $S/2$ will decompose into wedges of indecomposable spectra of an infinite number of homotopy types (even after suspensions).

At the prime 2, one can use idempotents in $\mathbb Z_2[\Sigma_3]$ to show any spectrum of the form $X 
\wedge X \wedge X$ decomposes as a wedge of the form $Y \vee Y \vee Z$.

When $X=S/2$, $Y = \Sigma S/2$  (which is likely what you meant) and $Z$ will have the same mod 2 cohomology (as an $A$-module) as $S/\eta \wedge S/2$. (Likely this cohomology module pins down the homotopy type.)

Added later ...

More generally, one can use known information about the modular representation theory of the symmetric groups to show the following: Suppose the mod 2 cohomology of $X$ is two dimensional.  The idempotents in the group ring  $\mathbb Z_2[\Sigma_n]$ can be used to (naturally) decompose $X^{\wedge n}$ into a wedge decomposition of the form
$$ X^{\wedge n} \simeq \bigvee_{i=0}^{[(n-1)/2]} a_n(i) X_n(i)$$
where $a_n(0)=1$ but the other $a_n(i)$'s might be hard to compute.  [That indexing set corresponds to 2-regular Young diagrams with two columns: pairs $(i,j)$ with $0 \leq i < j$ and $i+j=n$.]

If $X$ was $\mathbb RP^2$, $\mathbb CP^2$, $\mathbb HP^2$, or the Octonian projective plane, then the spectrum $X_{2^k}(0)$ will have  $Sq^{2^{k+c}}$ acting nontrivially, with $c=0,1,2,3$ corresponding to the four examples.  I don't know if these pieces further decompose or are atomic. Maybe $H^*(X_n(i); \mathbb Z/2)$ doesn't decompose as a direct sum as an $A$-module in our four examples.

Comment: Hi Nick, I have some confusions which you may be able to clear up for me. Does $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for you mean the $2$-adics or the integers mod two? If the latter, since $2$ does not act as the zero endomorphism of $S/2$, how does the mod two group ring of $\Sigma_n$ act on the $n$-fold smash product of $S/2$? Fortunately, idempotents in the mod two group ring lift to the $2$-adic group ring. Is this what you intend? Finally, you seem to know which idempotents act as zero on the tensor powers. Can you explain this? Sorry for all the questions - Cheers, Dave

Comment: @DaveBenson Yes, idempotents lift.  And at the prime 2 only, I know which primitive idempotents have nonzero image on the n-fold tensor power of a vector space (char 2) of a fixed dimension d.  Answer: those which correspond to 2-regular partitions of n with at most d columns.  (The proof of this is something I figured out awhile ago, and is too long to put into a MathOverflow comment, or answer.)

Comment: I found a reference for this: [Jie Wu, homotopy theory of suspensions of the projective plane](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0769) (working unstably, in fact). Is there a good reference for the stable decomposition of $X^{\otimes n}$ under the action of $\Sigma_n$? This stuff was also important in Devinatz-Hopkins-Smith's proof of the nilpotence theorem, but it seems that Jeff Smith's work never appeared in print...

Comment: @TimCampion  For this splitting problem, Jie Wu's memoir that you found sends one to [Selick, Paul  and Wu, Jie, On functorial decompositions of self-smash products, Manuscripta Math. 111 (2003), 435–457].   It is nice to see that I gave the same answer as they found! Their techniques are the same as those used by Jeff Smith, and Lionel Schwartz (see his unstable A-modules book), and me with Dave Carlisle in the 1980s, or with Chris Lloyd just recently.  In all these cases, there is no difference between stable splittings and splittings after just one suspension.